# My app is crashing and log messgaes say fatal exception : MAIN cannot find resource id #0X0

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

//THIS IS THE JAVA FILE FOR ARRAY ADAPTER , MY CUSTOM CLASS IS WORD 
 package com.example.android.miwok;

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
// I WANT TO CREATE A CUSTOM ADAPTER 
public class WordsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG=WordsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    public WordsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);
    }//this is the constructor for WordsAdapter


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView=convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }


        Word currentword=getItem(position);

        TextView miwokTranslation=(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);// I HAVE DEFINED THE VIEWS 

        assert currentword != null;
        miwokTranslation.setText(currentword.getMiwokTranslation()); //THESE METHODS HAVE BEEN DEFINED


        TextView defaultTranslation=(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);

        defaultTranslation.setText(currentword.getDefaultTranslation());

        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

I HAVE CREATED THE CUSTOM CLASS WORD AND CHECKED FOR ALL POSSIBLE ERRORS BUT STILL MY APP KEEPS CRASHING.

Comment: Please... DON'T SHOUT!

Comment: Please, create a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and formulate the question as a question.

Comment: Remove the `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` line in `WordsAdapter`'s `getView()` method.

Comment: This worked ! Thank you so much @MikeM. And ill be careful about not repeating my questions

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the line where you are setting text in textview. One of your getter function must be returning int value 0 so android is searching for Resource reference of 0x0. Use String.valueOf when setting int value on TextView. e.g.

```
 defaultTranslation.setText(String.valueOf(currentword.getDefaultTranslation()));
```

Comment: Tried doing this but didnt work